# Facebook API - Advanced Search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to replicate some functionality of the Facebook web interface via the API and am a bit stuck.  Basically, via the web site I can enter 'Favorite pages of people named "jim"' in the search box and get a slew of results, but I haven't found a way to replicate this type of query via the API.  Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Graph Search is not available through the Graph API. So no

Answer (score 0):

As WizKid commented, Graph Search is not available with the API, you can only use the Search API for searching: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#search

Keep in mind that public search and news feed search are not available in v2.0 anymore, see changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog